Why the Custom Colour works directly when assigned to tailwind css but not when created a constant in next js
Code Demo
When I try to create constants for reusing some colour components, I face the issue that the colours are not applied correctly. I have attached the demo for the same as well as the screenshot

But when used the CSS colour values directly in the tailwind it works,
for example
<button
    className={`text-[${WHITE}] border border-[${YELLOW}] px-5 h-12 ${josefinSans.className}`} onClick={onClick}>
    <span>{text}</span>
</button>

does not works

but
<button
    className={`text-[#FFF8F5] border border-[#E1B168] px-5 h-12 ${josefinSans.className}`} onClick={onClick}>
    <span>{text}</span>
</button>

works

Please explain the issue or what is wrong on my side or any possible solution

Does this answer your question? Trouble with Dynamic Color in Tailwind Component

As per the documentation:

The most important implication of how Tailwind extracts class names is that it will only find classes that exist as complete unbroken strings in your source files.
If you use string interpolation or concatenate partial class names together, Tailwind will not find them and therefore will not generate the corresponding CSS:
Don’t construct class names dynamically
<div class="text-{{ error ? 'red' : 'green' }}-600"></div>

In the example above, the strings text-red-600 and text-green-600 do not exist, so Tailwind will not generate those classes.
Instead, make sure any class names you’re using exist in full:
Always use complete class names
<div class="{{ error ? 'text-red-600' : 'text-green-600' }}"></div>


You could:

Have the entire class in the variable like:
export default function Home() {
  const YELLOW = "border-[#E1B168]";
  const DARK_BLUE = "bg-[#292E36]";
  const GRAY = "#555555";
  const LIGHT_BLUE = "#343942";
  const WHITE = "text-[#FFF8F5]";

  return (
    <div>
      <div>Tailwind css</div>
      <header
        className={`${DARK_BLUE} flex flex-row justify-evenly py-20`}
      >
        <button
          className={`${WHITE} border ${YELLOW} px-5 h-12`}


Use the style attribute for dynamic colors:
export default function Home() {
  const YELLOW = "#E1B168";
  const DARK_BLUE = "#292E36";
  const GRAY = "#555555";
  const LIGHT_BLUE = "#343942";
  const WHITE = "#FFF8F5";

  return (
    <div>
      <div>Tailwind css</div>
      <header
        className="flex flex-row justify-evenly py-20"
        style={{ backgroundColor: DARK_BLUE }}
      >
        <button
          className="border px-5 h-12"
          style={{
            color: WHITE,
            borderColor: YELLOW,
          }}


safelist the classes, if you have a limited number of known colors:
module.exports = {
  safelist: [
    'bg-[#292E36]',
    'text-[#FFF8F5]',
    'border-[#E1B168]',
    // …
  ],
  // …
];



